# Flutter audio player music player time is not showed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, audio-player

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'dart:ui';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //setting the project url
  String img_cover_url =
      "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a7/a9/cb/a7a9cbcefc58f5b677d8c480cf4ddc5d.jpg";

  bool isPlaying = false;
  double value = 0;
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  Duration? duration = Duration(); //seconds: 0
  Duration? position = Duration();

  void initPlayer() async {
    await player.setSource(AssetSource("forest.mp3"));
    duration = await player.getDuration();
    player.onPositionChanged.listen((Duration d) {
      setState(() {
        value = d.inSeconds.toDouble();
      });
    }
    );
  }

  //init the player
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    initPlayer();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
            height: 300.0,
            width: 300.0,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/cover.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 28, sigmaY: 28),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              //setting the music cover
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/cover.jpg",
                  width: 250.0,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              const Text(
                "Summer",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36, letterSpacing: 6),
              ),
              //Setting the seekbar
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "${(value / 60).floor()} : ${(value % 60).floor()}",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Slider.adaptive(
                    onChanged: (v){
                      setState(() {
                        value = v;
                      });
                    },
                    min: 0.0,
                    max: duration!.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                    value: value,
                    onChangeEnd: (newValue) async{
                      setState((){
                        value = newValue;
                        print(newValue);
                      });
                      player.pause();
                      await player.seek(Duration(seconds: newValue.toInt()));
                      await player.resume();
                    },
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                  ),

                  Text(

                    "${duration!.inMinutes} : ${duration!.inSeconds% 60}",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 60.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white38),
                    ),
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTapDown: (details) {
                        player.setPlaybackRate(0.5);
                      },
                      onTapUp: (details) {
                        player.setPlaybackRate(1);
                      },
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.fast_rewind_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 60.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink),
                      ),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () async{

                          if (isPlaying) {
                            await player.pause();
                            setState((){
                              isPlaying = false;
                            });
                          } else {
                            await player.resume();
                            setState((){
                              isPlaying = true;
                            });
                            player.onPositionChanged.listen(
                                  (position) {
                                setState((){
                                  value = position.inSeconds.toDouble();
                                });
                              },
                            );
                            setState(()  async {
                              duration =  await player.getDuration() as Duration?;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          isPlaying ? Icons.pause: Icons.play_arrow,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 60.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white38),
                    ),
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTapDown: (details) {
                        player.setPlaybackRate(2);
                      },
                      onTapUp: (details) {
                        player.setPlaybackRate(1);
                      },
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.fast_forward_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is flutter music player application using audioplayer.
I want to show the time it played and total music time length for example like below.

1.23 ----- slider ----- 3.14

Only when I click the play button, it shows the total music time length. Before clicking the button, it shows 0.0. But I want it to show total time length from when the page is showed.

Could anyone help me with this?